# Prove using Epsilon: $a_n:=e^{-n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> I have a sequence $(a_n)$ which is defined as $a_n:=e^{-n}$. I need to
>    use the definition of convergence to show that $a_n \to 0$ if $n \to
>  ∞$. The question is, how big should $N$ be chosen, so that $\lvert a_n-0 \lvert < 0.001$ for every $n\ge N$?

Using the definition as $\lvert a_x-a \lvert < {...} < \epsilon $ I have following so far:

Let $\epsilon >0$, we have $\lvert a_n-a \lvert =\lvert e^{-n} - 0\lvert=e^{-n}<\epsilon$

$e^{-n}<\epsilon \iff -n<ln(\epsilon) \iff n>-ln(\epsilon)$

Are my calculations correct so far? How do I proceed from this step on to complete the proof?

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right so far. Now you want to know how big $n$ needs to be for $\epsilon = 0.001,$ and per your calculation, that's just $ -\ln(0.001)\approx 6.9,$ so you need $n\ge 7.$